# Whitelabel Error Page There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm starting spring studies, I'm following a tutorial the same way, but it returns an error:

[image]

Here's my code :

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.Student.Student;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Year;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
   }

   @GetMapping
   public List<Student> Students(){
      return List.of(
            new Student(
                  1L,
                  "Mohamed",
                  "Mohamed@gmail.com",
                  LocalDate.of(1999, Month.MARCH, 28),
                  23
            )
      );
   }
}
```

`

i already created the class but it doesen't show in the screen as a json and i don't know why ?

Btw i commented the JPA part in pom.xml cuz i'm not gonna use db yet

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @xerx593 can i know why ?

Comment: i added logging.level.web=debug in application.properties but it still the same issue @xerx593

Comment: but as i saw in the tutorial it works with the same settiges i have !!

Comment: `@GetMapping("students")` was the fix!!! `logging.level...` was regarding "why so?"!

Comment: I understand you but why should we use a path if we are workung in the main class ??

Comment: i tried API Layer and it works good

Comment: i don't trust video tutorial, thus confirmed myself! :) it's true: with spring-boot:2.7.6 it works (on "default mapping") with spring-boot:3 i get 404!

Comment: got it: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-mvc-and-webflux-url-matching-changes !

Comment: ..but still activating this deprecated setting (`setUseTrailingSlashMatch`), doesn't fix.. ;( only `@GetMapping("/")` fixes this (particular issue)

Comment: Yes i got you, you're right in this version of spring we must add the path